# Why does an electron lose all of its energy in a resistor?

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity, electric-circuits, electrons, electrical-resistance

Why does the electron uses nearly all of its energy for one resistor in a simple circuit made of a battery, wire, and resistor?

I really need to know what happens exactly at the atomic level in the circuit; in other words:

What happens to the electrons to lose about 99.99% of the energy in the resistor and the remaining negligible amount of energy on the wire?

Comment: Did you read the Wiki article [Drude model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drude_model) I linked you to in comments on your previous question? Do you have any specific questions about it?

Comment: If you want to know exactly at the atomic level, then you will have to take a class on solid state physics.

Comment: @ThePhoton really thanks for your help. I read it quickly not focusing on it much because of my midyear tests. I have just one small question that is found in the comments of my previous question.  Thank you again, appreciate it.

Comment: @CuriousOne i just don't want to go so deep about it. Just want like a brief explanation on it.

Comment: OK... that's what I thought. The Photon is right, the Drude model is probably as simple as it gets. You can make it more complicated than that, but it's not really necessary for what you want to know.

Answer (score 1):

A resistor is not a free electron metallic structure but a complex metallic chemical composition. Some electrons in a drift field will actually pass through the complete lattice. This becomes the resultant drift field current through the system. Others will collide with the outer shells of the molecules of the complex material and cause them to jump and jiggle so creating infra red radiation in which the resultant photons at infra red wavelength collide with other molecules and cause thermodynamic heating. Thus the resistor gets hot. None of the energy is lost it just changes from electrical to thermodynamic.